# Excel VBA - Run macro before save

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking around on how to call my macro just before I save my document. I found this, but when I put my code inside it, it doesn't do anything. So I presume I'm missing something.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 

Set shtVO = Sheets("Voice orders")
endRowVO = shtVO.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Row = 11 To endRowVO
    If IsEmpty(shtVO.Cells(Row, 23).Value) = False Then
        If shtVO.Cells(Row, 3).Value <> shtVO.Cells(Row, 23) Then
            If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*MIG*" Then
            Else
                shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value + "MIG"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you put this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: In the what? I'm sorry, this is all new.

Comment: What is not working? What were you trying to do before save?

Comment: Before the save I just called upon the macro. But I will be using this on a shared .xlsm file and because not all users will know how to use I want to "automate" it in this way. We make sure everyone saves after each line they edit, thus the macro is called.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Place your code in the `ThisWorkbook` module

[image: Place your code here]

Comment: Your Workbook_BeforeSave event may also not be executed when you are in Design mode, so make sure to exit Design mode before you save your workbook.