# VBA to remove special characters before saving workbook

Tags: vba, excel, special-characters

I found this function to remove special characters.

```
Function Remove_Characters(s As String) As String
Static RegEx As Object
    If RegEx Is Nothing Then
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\\|/|:|\*|""|\?|<|>\|| "
        End With
    End If
Remove_Characters = RegEx.Replace(s, "")
End Function
```

What I want to know is how to use this to automatically remove all special characters from certain cells range (B47:L47,B51:L148) before saving the workbook?

Comment: Loop through the collection of cells in specific range and call above function inside every step of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read my comment to the question. This should help you:

```
Dim rng As Range, c As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("B47:L47,B51:L148")
For Each c In rng.Cells
    c.Value = Remove_Characters(c.Value)
Next c
```

Comment: Works if the range is a single cell address but if I put ("B47:L47,B51:L148") it returns run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Ohhhh, i forgot to add that you have to specify range as `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WshName").Range("Address")`. If this won't help, please let me know.

Comment: `For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("B47:L47,B51:L148")` returns run-time error '9': subscript out of range. Is that the correct syntax?

Comment: Please, see updated answer ;) I tested it and does not get any error.

Comment: I call this sub in ThisWorkbook with `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
        Cancel as Boolean)` I don't get any errors when the workbook is saved from Excel, but when I save file from MS Visual Basic editor it still gives me "Run-time error '9': subscript out of range" error.

Comment: I will do some more testing. Anyway, thank You for all the help!

Comment: You're very welcome. I keep fingers crossed for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the Workbook_BeforeSave event. This code will run whenever someone pushes save. The next step is to loop through your ranges and run your function.

Similar answer can be found: [Excel VBA - Run macro before save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365417/excel-vba-run-macro-before-save)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
        Cancel as Boolean) 
    a = MsgBox("Do you really want to save the workbook?", vbYesNo) 
    If a = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```